# Proper way to inherit fields from a Base Class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, base-class

Is the following code below good enough or should something like an interface or abstract class be used?

I had some common code, but I did not see a reason for an abstract class or an interface.

Also, there is no way to tell serviceClient came from BaseTask without exploring or hovering over it.  Is there something in each Task1 and Task2 to indicate this?

```
public class BaseTask
{
    private string configValue1 = "abc";
    private string configValue2 = "def";

    public ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient(configValue1,configValue2);
}

public class Task1 : BaseTask
{
    public void RunTask()
    {
        serviceClient.RunTask1();
    }

}

public class Task2 : BaseTask
{
    public void RunTask()
    {
        serviceClient.RunTask2();
    }

}

public class BaseTask
{
    private readonly string configValue1 = "abc";
    private readonly string configValue2 = "def";

    private readonly ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient(configValue1,configValue2);

    public ServiceClient ServiceClient { get{ return serviceClient;} }
}

public class Task1 : BaseTask
{
    public void RunTask()
    {
        ServiceClient.RunTask1();
    }

}

public class Task2 : BaseTask
{
    public void RunTask()
    {
        ServiceClient.RunTask2();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Habib - Sorry I'll change it to the word fields. Just mixed up my terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architectually I would just make `serviceClient` a read-only property.  Stylistically I would follow proper casing conventions for .NET:

```
private ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient(configValue1,configValue2);

public ServiceClient ServiceClient
{
    get { return serviceClient; }
}
```

It may also make sense to make `RunTask` virtual since the implementations you show are the same (and it allows you to override it in other implementations if necessary):

```
public virtual void RunTask()
{
    serviceClient.RunTask1();
}
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but how can I make the call to `ServiceClient.RunTask1()` more explicit, so if someone is looking at the code, they can quickly tell `ServiceClient` comes from `BaseTask`, something similar to `BaseTask.ServiceClient.RunTask1()`

Comment: You could use `base.serviceClient` to indicate is comes from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't make sense to create an instance of `BaseTask` on its own then make it abstract to prevent anyone from doing so. This also make your intention clear (ie that `BaseTask` should only be derived from).

I'd also recommend not making variables public. Instead hide them behind properties.

Comment: Good point about abstract.  My actual variables are private except for 1 which I use in another class.

Comment: I actually changed all of them to private now and used a public property as D Stanley pointed out, so I have something like `ServiceClient.RunTask1()` in my `Task1` class, but is there a way to make the call more explicit, such as `BaseTask.ServiceClient.RunTask1()` so it is more clear?

Comment: @xaisoft - I don't think making it more explicit (by writing `BaseTask.ServiceClient.RunTask1()`) is a good idea as it exposes the implementation to the user of the class. Having a `RunTask` method on your derived class (on on the base) it much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You don;t currently have any properties. If you need your specific value, try the below.

```
public class BaseTask
{
  private string _configValue1 = "abc";
  private string _configValue2 = "def";
  private ServiceClient _serviceClient1 = new ServiceClient(configValue1,configValue2);

  Public ServiceClient ServiceClient1
   {
    get
     {
        return _serviceClient1;
     }
   set
     {
        serviceClient1 = value;
     }  
 }

Public string ConfigValue1
 {
   get
     {
        return _configValue1;
     }
   set
     {
        _configValue1= value;
     }
 }

Public string ConfigValue2
 {
   get
     {
        return _configValue2;
     }
   set
     {
        _configValue2 = value;
     }
 }
```